# checkbox returning only 0 in formData

Tags: ajax, laravel

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="visa">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="visa">
```

**AJAX:**

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("update-form"));
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "teachers/" + $('#update-data').attr("value"),
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
                data:formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
            alert("updated");
            }
            });
```

even if my checkbox is checked or unchecked i am getting 0.

if i add following code, it shows `0 0` in console. it should return `1` if it is checked.

```
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair);
}
```

Comment: why you have given type="hidden" with same name as type="checkbox"?

Comment: if it's unchecked i need to get it's value as 0, by default i am not getting that.

Comment: Give unique name for both form elements. You given 'visa' for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .is(':checked')

In your html

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="visa" id="hiddenInput">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheckbox">
```

In your js

```
$("#myCheckbox").on('change',function(){
    if($("#myCheckbox").is(':checked'))
        $('#hiddenInput').val(1);  
    else{
         $('#hiddenInput').val(0);  
    }
});
```

If you have multiple checkbox and lets say
like this below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hiddenInput1">
<input type="checkbox" id="hiddenInput2">
```

You can loop checkbox and append to your data

add this line above ajax

```
var checkbox = $("#myForm").find("input[type=checkbox]");

$.each(checkbox, function(key, val) {
    formData.append($(this).attr('id'), this.is(':checked'))
});
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, what i have multiple checkboxes, i will have to repeat this code again and again?

Comment: @Fayakon you can use loop

Comment: that would be interesting to know.

Comment: i replaced your code with this, $(' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            $(this).val(1);
    else{
     $(this).val(0);
        }
    });

Comment: it returns always zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you need checkbox value by default `0` if it's unchecked return `1` else `0` you can use the below code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="visa" value="0" id="custom">

$('#custom').on('change', function(){
     this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
     alert(this.value);
}).change();
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is returning 1, but how to get 0 if it's unchecked.

Comment: @Fayakon First, Please remove `<input type="hidden" value="0" name="visa">` 
If you uncheck checkbox alert value `0`

Comment: it shows 0 in alert, but not submitting 0  in formData when unchecked.

Comment: @Fayakon You need to append value into `formData` when checkbox value change.